# Does not contain a definition for 'SetValue & GetValue'

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{ 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PointsCollection", typeof(PointsCollection), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata()); 

    public PointsCollection PointsCollection 
    { 
     get { return (PointsCollection) GetValue(PointsCollectionProperty); } 
     set { SetValue(PointsCollectionProperty, value); } 
    } 

    public MainWindow() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        PointsCollection = new PointsCollection(); 
        PointsCollection.Add(new Point(1, 1)); 
        PointsCollection.Add(new Point(2, 2)); 
        PointsCollection.Add(new Point(3, 3)); 
    } 
    void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        PointsCollection.Add(new Point(1, 1)); 
    } 
} 

public class PointsCollection : ObservableCollection<Point> 
{ 
}
```

Does not contain a definition for `SetValue & GetValue`. Getting an error in the above dependency property.

Comment: What is unclear about the error? You don't have methods GetValue or SetValue and you are trying to use those.

Comment: Thanks..!
But, issue with DependencyObject class.

Comment: Sure that Window is actually `System.Windows.Window`?

Comment: Yes Clemens...!

Comment: Everything seems to be fine, except a missing `}` under `PointsCollection`. If this was the full source, it is a namespace issue.

Comment: Thanks Aly El-Haddad..!
I'm sure that, not an issue with ' } ' or namespace..!

Comment: Are you sure you have `PresentationFramework`, and `WindowsBase` in project references?

Comment: Yes Aly El-Haddad..!